# When deploying a .Net app with reference missing on client system, will it crash on launch or throw an exception when the method is used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, deployment

I want to use a .dll file that is only on newer Windows systems.  But, I have lots of older systems using my software.

I'm only using this DLL for one function, and it's not a core feature.

Will the software fail to launch, throw an exception on launch, or when the function is called that references that missing library?

If I can get by with simply handling the missing reference exception for that one method, then I'd be happy.

But, if it fails to launch, or crashes without being inside the one function that references the library that I expect ten percent of my customers to be missing, then I have to strip out the library.

Having ten of the customers have to use a fallback method, after handling an exception, is fine.  Having ten percent of the customers crash on launch because of a missing reference is unacceptable.

So, is a missing reference in a WPF/.Net application dead on arrival, or can I catch the exception in the one function and do something else?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: [For reference](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded)

Comment: Could you make a dummy app to test this? Create a console app which uses a class library dll, build it with reference to the dll, remove the dll and run the exe in bin folder

Comment: That article is really useful.
Haven't tried yet.  I do remember loading assemblies by reflection before, and it's probably a good thing to do just to avoid issues.
Basically just wanting to run a PowerShell command in System.Management.Automation, but I know there are plenty of users that don't have it on their system yet.